# Expressing the joint probabilities in a $2 \times 2$ table in terms of the marginal probabilities and the odds ratio

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, contingency-tables

Given a $2 \times 2$ contingency table with cell probabilities $$(\pi_{00}, \pi_{01},\pi_{10}, \pi_{11})$$ and marginal probabilities $$\pi_{+1}=\pi_{01}+\pi_{11}$$ and $$\pi_{1+}=\pi_{10}+\pi_{11},$$ is it possible to express the cell probabilities only in terms of the marginal probabilities and the odds ratio $$\theta = \frac{\pi_{11}\pi_{00}}{(\pi_{10}\pi_{01})},$$ i.e. can we find a set of functions $f_{ij}$ for which
$$\pi_{ij} = f_{ij}(\theta, \pi_{1+}, \pi_{+1})?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done as follows. We have the following system of equations
\begin{align*}
\pi_{01} + \pi_{11} &= \pi_{+1}\\
\pi_{10} + \pi_{11} &= \pi_{1+}\\
\pi_{00} + \pi_{01} + \pi_{10} + \pi_{11} &= 1\\
\theta\pi_{10}\pi_{01} - \pi_{11}\pi_{00} &= 0
\end{align*}
So, given $\pi_{+1}$, $\pi_{1+}$, and $\theta$, we have a system of four equations in the four unknowns $\pi_{00}$, $\pi_{01}$, $\pi_{10}$, and $\pi_{11}$, and we want to show that this system has at most one solution satisfying $0 \leq \pi_{ij} \leq 1$. We can assume without loss of generality that $\theta \leq 1$ (e.g., by swapping the two rows of the table if necessary). Using the first three equations, we can express all of the unknowns in terms of $\pi_{11}$:
\begin{align*}
\pi_{01} &= \pi_{+1} - \pi_{11}\\
\pi_{10} &= \pi_{1+} - \pi_{11}\\
\pi_{00} &= 1 - \pi_{+1} - \pi_{1+} + \pi_{11}
\end{align*}
Substituting these into $\theta\pi_{10}\pi_{01} - \pi_{11}\pi_{00} = 0$, we are left with a quadratic equation in $\pi_{11}$:
$$\theta(\pi_{1+}-\pi_{11})(\pi_{+1}-\pi_{11}) - \pi_{11}(1-\pi_{+1}-\pi_{1+}+\pi_{11}) = 0$$
which can be expressed in standard form:
$$(1-\theta)\pi_{11}^2 + (1-(1-\theta)(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}))\pi_{11} - \theta\pi_{+1}\pi_{1+} = 0$$
This has a unique solution satisfying $\pi_{11} \geq 0$, namely
$$\pi_{11} = 
\begin{cases}
\pi_{+1}\pi_{1+},&\text{if }\theta=1,\\
\frac12\left(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta}+\sqrt{(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta})^2+\frac{4\theta\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}{1-\theta}}\right),&\text{if }\theta<1
\end{cases}
$$
Note here that the other solution to the quadratic (with $-$ in front of the square root) can be easily seen to lead to a negative value of $\pi_{11}$, which is not of interest.

The work above provides a complete solution, but it may also be desirable to put the case $\theta>1$ into an explicit form, which we can now do. In this case, as mentioned above, we can consider the $2 \times 2$ table obtained by swapping the two rows of the given table. Let us denote the parameters of the new table by $\pi_{ij}^*, \pi_{+1}^*, \pi_{1+}^*, \theta^*$. We then have the following relationships between the parameters of the original and new tables:
\begin{align*}
\pi_{00}^* &= \pi_{10}\\
\pi_{01}^* &= \pi_{11}\\
\pi_{10}^* &= \pi_{00}\\
\pi_{11}^* &= \pi_{01}\\
\pi_{1+}^* &= 1-\pi_{1+}\\
\pi_{+1}^* &= \pi_{+1}\\
\theta^* &= 1/\theta
\end{align*}
Thus the new table satisfies $\theta^*<1$, so we may apply the solution above to obtain
$$\textstyle\pi_{11}^* = \frac12\left(\pi_{1+}^* +\pi_{+1}^* -\frac1{1-\theta^*}+\sqrt{(\pi_{1+}^*+\pi_{+1}^*-\frac1{1-\theta^*})^2+\frac{4\theta^*\pi_{1+}^*\pi_{+1}^*}{1-\theta^*}}\right) $$
Substituting using the known relationships, this can be expressed in terms of the original table
$$\textstyle\pi_{01} = \frac12\left(1-\pi_{1+} +\pi_{+1} -\frac1{1-\theta^{-1}}+\sqrt{(1-\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta^{-1}})^2+\frac{4\theta^{-1}(1-\pi_{1+})\pi_{+1}}{1-\theta^{-1}}}\right)$$
Using the relationship $\pi_{01} = \pi_{+1} - \pi_{11}$, after some algebraic manipulation this becomes
$$\pi_{11} = \textstyle\frac12\left(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta}-\sqrt{(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta})^2+\frac{4\theta\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}{1-\theta}}\right) $$
Therefore, an explicit solution covering all possible cases for $\theta$ can be written:
$$\pi_{11} = 
\begin{cases}
\pi_{+1}\pi_{1+},&\text{if }\theta=1,\\
\frac12\left(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta}+\sqrt{(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta})^2+\frac{4\theta\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}{1-\theta}}\right),&\text{if }\theta<1, \\
\frac12\left(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta}-\sqrt{(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-\frac1{1-\theta})^2+\frac{4\theta\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}{1-\theta}}\right),&\text{if }\theta>1.
\end{cases}
$$
Some care would need to be taken when implementing this, because the formula above is numerically unstable as $\theta$ approaches 1. We can apply some algebraic manipulation to put it into a numerically stable form, which also conveniently eliminates the need for cases:
$$\pi_{11} = 
\frac{2\theta\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}{1-(1-\theta)(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}) + \sqrt{((1-\theta)(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1})-1)^2 + 4\theta(1-\theta)\pi_{1+}\pi_{+1}}}
$$

Comment: Excellent. I had the same thought later and came to the same solution. Two points: I believe your last equation is incomplete. You forget the solution where the root is deducted. Furthermore the $\pm$ is not contingent on $\theta$ as you imply. It would be interesting to deduce the conditions under which the root has to be added or deducted to have $\pi_{11} \le 1$ (or even both is permissible), but the condition you give (i.e. $\theta <1$) is incorrect. When both is permissible there even exist two solutions for all parameters.

Comment: The $\pm$ was not forgotten; I did not include the other solution because it has $\pi_{11}<0$ which is not what we seek. I still believe that the formula as written is correct; do you have a counterexample, or what do you believe the error is?

Comment: Sorry I got confused by the signs in my and your notation. I believe you should simply add the $-$ before the square root with condition $\theta>1$. See suggested edit.

Comment: Well, my approach was to handle the case $\theta>1$ by swapping the rows to bring it back to $\theta<1$ (in the "without loss of generality" at the beginning), but I suppose it's nicer to have the more explicit solution if this is right. To justify it, it seems you'd need to show that the '$+$' sign in the case $\theta>1$ leads to a violation of one of the constraints $0 \leq \pi_{ij} \leq 1$, which is probably true, although it doesn't appear to be obvious just from looking at the formula.

Comment: Alternatively, one could work through the implications of swapping the rows (replacing $\pi_{1+}$ with $1-\pi_{1+}$ and $\theta$ by $1/\theta$) and in this way derive the $\theta>1$ case from the $\theta<1$ case. It's certainly believable that it works out the way you suggest.

Comment: hmmm... after debugging my code I come to the tentative conclusion that only the third equation ($-$) always (i.e. for all combinations I tried) gives admissible solutions for **all** parameters (i.e. not only $\pi_{11}$).

Comment: Yes, you are right that it works out this way for $\theta>1$. I've extended my answer to give a proof of why this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible. We have 4 unknowns $\pi_{ij}$ which get reduced to 3, since $\sum_{i,j}\pi_{ij}=1$. You have 3 other equations. Then:

$$\theta=\frac{\pi_{11}\pi_{00}}{(\pi_{1+}-\pi_{11})(\pi_{+1}-\pi_{11})}.$$

Now write $\pi_{00}=1-(\pi_{01}+\pi_{10}+\pi_{11})=1-(\pi_{1+}+\pi_{+1}-2\pi_{11}+\pi_{11})$.

Plug this into the $\theta$ equation and you get a quadratic equation for $\pi_{11}$ in terms of $\theta,\pi_{+1},\pi_{1+}$. Then $\pi_{01}=\pi_{+1}-\pi_{11}$ and $\pi_{10}=\pi_{1+}-\pi_{11}$.